# Missing package libemu-dev in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: package-management, software-installation, 20.04, source-packages, unsupported-packages

libemu-dev package exists for Ubuntu 18.04 but it seems to be missing for Ubuntu 20.04. Has libemu-dev been discontinued in 20.04  or will it be added in the future? Is there a way I can install libemu-dev in 20.04?

https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/bionic/universe/base/libemu-dev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libe/libemu/libemu2_0.2.0+git20120122-1.2build1_amd64.deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libe/libemu/libemu-dev_0.2.0+git20120122-1.2build1_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./libemu2_0.2.0+git20120122-1.2build1_amd64.deb ./libemu-dev_0.2.0+git20120122-1.2build1_amd64.deb
```